# Error converting data type varchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to return 'ItemId' column value of 'item' table using stored procedure based on the input value of 'Name' column which is of varchar type, but whenever I pass any value to stored procedure it is returning me an error: **Error converting data type varchar to int.**

```
 create procedure RetrieveId
(@itemId int output,@Name varchar(30))
As
Begin
If exists(Select  * from item where [Name] = @Name)
Begin
 Select @itemId = itemid from item 
  where [Name] = @Name
 return @itemId
End
Else
return 1
End
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
RetrieveId 'asf'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to match parameters: The RETURN does not populate the OUTPUT parameters: your assignment to @itemid does that.

```
DECLARE @item int
EXEC RetrieveId @item OUTPUT, 'asf'
```

Also, your stored proc is too complex. RETURN is not a good choice for returning data from stored procs and the EXISTS is unnecessary. In this case, @itemId will be NULL if not found

```
create procedure RetrieveId
   @itemId int output,
   @Name varchar(30)
As
   Select @itemId = itemid
   from item 
   where [Name] = @Name
GO
```