# How to convert data type varchar to int in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I am new in SQL server and I want to make a code in SQL server by passing parameter but showing this error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure NewOderNo, Line 12
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ORD1503200001' to data type int.
```

And here is my code:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[NewOderNo]
@custid varchar(50)
AS
declare @cid int
declare @par int

BEGIN
--CONVERT(varchar,ISNULL(@cid,0))
set @par= (select substring(ord_no,8,1) from tbl_OrderMaster)
print @par
        select @cid=id from tbl_Supplier where id= @custid;
        SELECT 'ORD'+convert(varchar,(YEAR( GETDATE() ) % 100))+ CONVERT(varchar(2), getdate(), 101) +CONVERT(varchar,ISNULL(@cid,0)) + RIGHT('00000' + convert(varchar,(ISNULL(MAX(ord_no),0)+1)),5) as order_no from tbl_OrderMaster where @par = @custid;

END


--exec NewOderNo '2'
```

The type of the table column ord_no is varchar. Any suggestions please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error converting data type varchar to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757847/error-converting-data-type-varchar-to-int)

Comment: firstly, `@par` is an `int` and you're trying to set it to a varchar when you do `substring`. Secondly, the line where you set `@par`, the query in brackets will require all rows as there's no `where` clause or `top 1` on it, so it won't work unless you add a filter. Thirdly, I assume you want your `substring` to return a `numeric` portion of the `ord_no`, which clearly you aren't doing correctly as the result of the `substring` is `ORD1503200001`, which isn't numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the variable @par as a varchar as in your script, you're trying to set this variable which is currently an int to a varchar data type.

e.g.

```
declare @par varchar(50)
```

Instead of

```
declare @par int
```